# How can I fetch the most recently added document using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to fetch the most recent document in MongoDB using mongoose.

Every method I have tried so far gives me the oldest document on record.

I've tried sorting by date, and created_at

Tried both ascending and descending, both return the oldest document.

https://paste.heckyou.ml/odofomasel.js

The value returned should be the most recently added document.

Comment: `crated_at` is not `created_at`.

Comment: I know, I didn't have that saved in my code since I changed it so I added that in when I copy-pasted the block and accidentally made a typo. Still can't get this to work and I've been trying for hours

Answer (score 0):

This will give you one last document for a collection

```
db.collectionName.findOne({}, {sort:{$natural:-1}})
```

$natural:-1 means order opposite of the one that records are inserted in.

mongo CLI syntax is: `db.collectionName.find({}).sort({$natural:-1}).limit(1)`